# How to do K-means with normalized TF-IDF

Tags: normalization, cluster-analysis, k-means, tf-idf

I want some guidance here. I've just been trying to normalize the TF-IDF results for my project. So, I am thinking ahead *what's next after TF-IDF*? I wanted to do k-means clustering onto those normalized TF-IDF but *is it the time already*? before this I created the index with Lucene, and if possible I *don't want to use Mahout*, because I'm using Windows (don't want to use cygwin either).

Any *suggestion on what (and how) to do k-means* with these lucene-ed and tf-idf-ed results? I'm lost here..

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve. cluster the results ? or something else ?

Comment: Yes I want to cluster the results. then the results should be in clusters where we can view them by selecting the cluster no. any code examples or links on how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into '''spherical k-means''', as:

- regular k-means is tied to Euclidean distance
- regular k-means does not work well for high-dimensional sparse data

Comment: all right, I want to make this clear; I just want to use the original k-means lloyd algorithm, so, right now I want your help to suggest how can I get the clustering results. cuz right now I was told by my lacturer that I can directly use the un-normalized TF-IDF to do clustering but I don't know hoe to apply it.. I already got the double[][]matrix var up... guys please show me the way... I'm lost

Comment: Why don't you ask your lecturer then? I mean, you can use anything. You can apply k-means to 0 vectors. The result just won't be too useful IMHO.

Comment: You can try k-means with non-euclidean distances. It will *run*, but it might not *converge* but chase its tail. You can apply it to binary data, but you then shouldn't be surprised to see non-binary centers and many clusters become empty. And you can apply it to high-dimensional data such as TF-IDF vectors, ignoring the well-known *curse of dimensionality*.

Comment: oh, so do you mean that euclidean distance need normalized vectors? cause you're suggesting me to try with non-euclidean distance.. But I thought that's the most famous distance measurement for original kmeans? thanks for replying though.

Comment: No. Euclidean distance needs *geometric* spaces. It is known to not work well for high-dimensional data. And it is *the* distance that k-means was designed for. For other distance functions the *mean* is likely not optimizing the variances, so it might not converge (so you shouldn't use other distances!).
Ask your lecturer about k-means and other distances!